# How to generate random numbers without repetitions from 0 to 100 of String type?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, random, key

I have a variable of type String which is id. I would like to generate a random String number from 0 to 100 into it without repeating, how can I do this

```
final String  keyRan = '0';
```

Comment: You could create a list of all eligible values and shuffle the list, then take and remove the first element to get the next randomized value.

Comment: If it is not allowed to repeat then it is not random :)

Comment: Try set instead of list

Comment: No matter what you do, the numbers 1 to 100 are repeated inside them!!

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Removing from a list is less efficient than shuffling.

Comment: @mmcdon20 Removing the first element is bad.  Better to remove the last element or to just increment an index.

Comment: @jamesdlin fair point, calling `removeLast()` on the list would be better than `removeAt(0)`. Incrementing a counter also works.

Comment: @mmcdon20 No need to remove values from a shuffled list, just iterate through the list.

Comment: @activout.se Professional statistician here, please stop spreading disinformation. You can have random sampling with replacement, in which case you can get repeats. You can also have random sampling without replacement (such as when you eat the cookie after picking one at random), in which case you don’t get repeats. With replacement has fixed probabilities of `1/#items` for choosing a particular item on each trial. Without replacement gives changing probabilities which are conditioned on what’s already been picked. But both sampling schemes are random.

Comment: @pjs that certainly works as well. Similar to incrementing an index as jamesdlin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet might help:

```
// generate a list of 0 to 100 (inclusive) as Strings
final numbers = List.generate(101, (index) => index.toString());

// shuffle those
numbers.shuffle();

// print each of them, just as an example here
numbers.forEach((number) => print(number));

// or take the last one each time
final number = numbers.removeLast();
```